# Flutter: I can't get data from the server due to an error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

Please help me with this problem:

When making a request to the server, I get the error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

I use retrofit for requests:

This Api Service Class:

```
    @RestApi(baseUrl: kBaseUrl)
abstract class RecipesApiService {
  factory RecipesApiService(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _RecipesApiService;

  @GET('my=endpoint')
  Future<HttpResponse<AboutResponse>> about();
}
```

This Response Model:

```
class AboutResponse {
  final String page;


  AboutResponse({this.page });

  factory AboutResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AboutResponse(
      page: json['page'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = page;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here the difficulty is that I receive a response from the server in this form:

```
{"page":"\u041e
\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438"}
```

and apparently he can not cast it into a Map<String, dynamic>.
I tried to change some code in the generated class to:

Api Service Generated Class

```
    @override
  Future<HttpResponse<AboutResponse>> about() async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _result = await _dio.request<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        'my=endpoint',
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        options: RequestOptions(
            method: 'GET',
            headers: <String, dynamic>{},
            extra: _extra,
            baseUrl: baseUrl),
        data: _data);
    final value = AboutResponse.fromJson(_result.data);
    final httpResponse = HttpResponse(value, _result);
    return httpResponse;
  }
```

and line:

```
final _result = await _dio.request<Map<String, dynamic>>
```

I changed to

```
final _result = await _dio.request<String>
```

and if I output "_result" to the console, then it will show me what comes from the server.

Please help, maybe I should make some settings in retrofit so that I can receive data from the server or can I look somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: There is an issue in the repository which is not been solved yet. https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/227

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the response is not being decoded from JSON, usually, dio does not need deserialization.

Try to decode JSON response in the model class.

```dart
  factory AboutResponse.fromJson(String json) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJSON = jsonDecode(json);
    return AboutResponse(
      page: decodedJSON['page'] as String,
    );
  }
```

Comment: i can't pass String in generated class to method fromJson, because the field _result return <Map<String, dynamic>>. Also the method jsonDecode "A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."